# ASp.net Website all images CSS styles are disappeared

Tags: asp.net

I created a website using ASP.Net, and used J-Query and CSS also the website working properly offline but when i uploading it on server all images, CSS- styles , every thing disappears .

Before uploading website i published website and i got files that i uploaded, but it is not working my website link in http://bloodcheckup4all.freetzi.com pls check it and give me solution

and my other question is that before uploading my website should i change the extension of Index.aspx to index.html?

Comment: It looks like you're uploading to a host that doesn't support .aspx or that isn't activated? The masterpage declaration line is appearing when it shouldn't.

Comment: No you can't change the file extension from  `Index.aspx` to `index.html`

Comment: looks like you have taken hosting from freetzi.com but it does not have .aspx support check here http://www.freewebhostingarea.com/

Answer (score 0):

**FIRST QUESTION:**

You should change the url of all your CSS images to use the web root as it's starting point, not a url *relative* to your style folder:

For example:

```
background: url('../Images/MyImage.png');
```

should be changed to:

```
background: url('/Images/MyImage.png');
```

This will keep you out of trouble.

**SECOND QUESTION**

No! The ASP.NET ISAPI will not handle (parse) the page if you change the extension (unless the ISAPI is specifically configured to do so, which I highly doubt).

You need to find a host that supports whatever version of the .NET framework your using.